# How to center elements in gridLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, grid-layout

I have a grid layout (3 columns and 3 rows).**I'm trying to put an image in the center of each square of the grid**. I played with margin's values a bit and got what I wanted in [the design view of activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP7fB.png)
But when I run the app on my phone the images aren't positioned in their correct places. [**this is how it looks in my phone**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3KZv.png).

I don't know what I did wrong. I'm a newbie in this so anything can be wrong really.
Here's the code of activity_main.xml:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="3"   />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="4" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="5"   />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="6" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="7"   />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="8" />

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fffaff0b"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play Again"
            android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="playAgain" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your imageview width and also add one property

```
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

in your all imageview

because you define

```
 android:layout_height="360dp"
```

of GridLayout and you set imageviews height width =90

but all screen not square so your GridLayout make Rectangle
and your imageview is square thats your imageview(square) not fit in Grid(Rectangle)

imageview width must be same or lessthen grid's width

Comment: So I need to make sure the grid is a square? how can I make the width of the grid equal to the width of the screen of the phone? I want to use the dimensions of the screen instead of a fixed number like 360dp.

Comment: DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

Comment: that get you screen height width, after thet you can dynamically set your gridview width == screen width using LayoutParams

Comment: and set gridview height == aslo the width of screen
thats make your grid layout square

Comment: Thanks @Birgu . I'll try what you said.

Comment: you can also set your images width programitally like imageview's width == screenwidth/3;

Comment: yeah that's why I wanted to get the screen width because I want to make sure **heightOfGrid = widthOfGrid = widthOfScreen**

Comment: one more thing its not compulsary that your gridview is square or rectangle...compulary is that imageivew's width and grid's porsion width must be same...so image can fit inside that box..ok?

Comment: hey so let's say I have **screenWidth** and this is my grid:                                                 `GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) findViewByI(R.id.gridLayout);`                         how do I set the grid's width? I didn't find any setWidth method.

Comment: try grid .getLayoutParams().height = screenwidth;
grid .getLayoutParams().width= screenwidth;

grid .requestLayout();

Answer (score 0):

For the given xml files and dimensions, you can't achieve that is required because you are using hardcoded dimensions and your background image is may be in one resolution may xhdpi or xxhdpi.
What you need to do is first create dimensions for different resolutions and then create different images for different resolutions for the background image and that will bind to specific screen.

You can use alternate xml file that I have modified to get above criteria and modify it accordingly and below xml file will use hardcoded dimensions but you can update it later.

[image: New Xml file will generate following view]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView3"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView4"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView5"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView6"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView7"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView8"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView9"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#fffaff0b"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="playAgain"
        android:text="Play Again" />
</LinearLayout>
```